# Apple sandbox tester "this field is invalid" for password

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I am having a weird problem when trying to create an Apple Sandbox Tester. I have entered valid information including a personal/valid email address, but no matter what I enter for the password, I get an error message that says, "This field is invalid". I have also tried in both Chrome and Safari - same result. Does anyone have any ideas?

I have tried every type of password I can think of with no luck. It doesn't tell me why the field is invalid, just that it is. It is not rejecting it because the passwords don't match. It tells me when they don't match.

I have also tried different valid email addresses - same result.

I have tried it on my MacBook, Android phone, and my iPad. I get the same result on all 3 devices.

[image]

Comment: checked browser console? cleared cache?

Comment: I have tried it on my Macbook, Android phone, and my iPad. I get the same result on all 3 devices.

Comment: The password should start with a letter and include capitals, smalls, and numbers, like "Heyheyheyho21". I find the interface in this form really bad. You need to fill in every field correctly, in order, or the form just freezes up. So first name, then tab to last name, then tab to email (does not have to be real), then password and confirm password, then secret question (I use "testing") and answer (I use "testingtesting"), then date and store country.

Comment: @matt Well I followed your instructions very carefully, and it finally worked. I could have sworn that I did it exactly like this the previous 10 times :P Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I know, crazy isn’t it? It’s just some sort of crappy HTML or JavaScript or something. You simply have to do every field without a mistake in order or it doesn’t work at all.

Comment: I’ll give my comment as an answer so you can accept and we can close this out. Might be useful for others, I suppose.

Comment: Might check network/XHR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The password should start with a letter and include capitals, smalls, and numbers, like "Heyheyheyho21”.

But I find the interface in this form really bad. You need to fill in *every* field *correctly, in order*, or the form just freezes up.

So first name, then tab to last name, then tab to email (does not have to be real), then password and confirm password, then secret question (I use "testing") and answer (I use "testingtesting"), then date and store country.

You will then be able to click Invite and move on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to discover what the problem is.
Open the JavaScript console, you should see a 409/Conflict status code with a link. Click the link and you will get a JSON with the error.

For me it was using spaces in the password. Once I sorted this out I received an email requiring verification which I did successfully.

Comment: The console.log itself might not be enough, might check Network/XHR

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was actually nothing wrong with the password though that was the error being pointed out by apple.

The problem was that I was using a mailinator email id instead of for ex: Google/Yahoo e-mail id. Once I created test email ids in Yahoo/Google, then it started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Password Must Contain One capital , small character ,number , special character and also greater than 8 characters. I resolved this issue in this way.
e.g "Ran@32431"